# Looping through rows to split values into new spreadsheets evenly

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I'm new to VBA and have been tasked with updating an existing macro to automate a portion of our workflow. Basically, the current macro takes the customer_ids from one spreadsheet and exports them into a new CSV file to be farmed out to salespeople by a manager. We have a program which can assign the customer to a salesperson directly, but the format MUST be a single column CSV file with customer_ids only, and each CSV file needs to be titled for each individual salesperson. My problem starts when there are multiple salespeople assigned to a single region. In this case, I need to loop through the customer_ids for the specific region and have them broken out equally amongst the salespeople of that region.

```
EX:
There are 2 salespeople for region A (call them A1 and A2),
and 2 other salespeople for region B (B1 and B2). 

customer_id | region
123                A
234                A
345                A
456                B
567                B
678                B
789                B
```

The above table needs to be filtered out such that customers 123, 234, 345 are evenly split between 2 new files: one for A1, and one for A2 (meaning one file will have an extra customer, which is fine). Same goes for customers 456, 567, 678, and 789 among the region B1 and B2 files.

I'm assuming I'll need a recursive loop to do this (although I hear that loops are bad in VBA). But I'm not sure where to start in order to distribute the customer_ids evenly between the new files.

I would really appreciate your help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
set A1 = Sheets.add
set A2 = Sheets.add
set B1 = Sheets.add
set B2 = Sheets.add
for each cell in customer_id column (replace this with the column)
    if cell.offset(0,1) = "A" Then
        if 1a >= 2a then
             A1.cells(1a,1) = cell
        else if 2a > 1a then
             A2.cells(2a,2) = cell
        end if
    Else If cell.offset(0,1) = "B" Then
        if 1b >= 2b then
             B1.cells(1a,1) = cell
        else if 2b > 1b then
             B2.cells(2a,2) = cell
        end if
    End if
next cell

dest = "C:\" ' Set where you want the files to be saved here

A1.SaveAs dest & A1, xlCSV '(Where A1 is your salesperson name)
A2.SaveAs dest & A2, xlCSV '(Where A2 is your salesperson name)
B1.SaveAs dest & B1, xlCSV '(Where B1 is your salesperson name)
B2.SaveAs dest & B2, xlCSV '(Where B2 is your salesperson name)
application.displayalerts = False
A1.delete
A2.delete
B1.delete
B2.delete
application.displayalerts = True
application.screenupdating = True
```

Warning: This is untested and I've just finished working since 7 this morning (it is now coming up 2 in the morning)

Comment: We elected to go through the SSIS package since we're more experienced with SQL. Your answer seems comprehensive so I'm accepting it.